# Property 'setParentKeyForNodeData' does not exist on type 'Model'. Did you mean 'setCategoryForNodeData'?

Tags: angular, gojs

I'm using gojs and I'm using organizational chart. There are 3 context menu exists. In "Remove Role", I'm getting `Property 'setParentKeyForNodeData' does not exist on type 'Model'. Did you mean 'setCategoryForNodeData'`
as error

**Code**

```
myDiagram.model.setParentKeyForNodeData(emp.data, node.findTreeParentNode().data.key);
```

I have mentioned the versions below,

```
"gojs": "^2.1.8",
"gojs-angular": "1.0.3",
"typescript": "~3.7.5"
```

In getting the proper functionality in organizational chart, but I'm unable to build the application as I'm getting error in that particular line

Comment: I think you should downgrade your go js  version. Kindly check for this link https://forum.nwoods.com/t/orgchart-editor-with-angular-code-errors/11786/5 for more clarification.

Comment: How do I downgrade the version?I have changed in package.json but getting same error and I have searched but unable to get any solution

Comment: Did you install npm packages after downgrade?

Comment: Which version of Angular are you using?  If you are using an old version of Angular, that would be the only reason to downgrade the version of GoJS.  In fact for performance reasons I recommend using the latest version of gojs-angular.

Comment: I'm using "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7" version and I'm using "gojs-angular": "1.0.3",version. In go.d.ts setParentKeyForNodeData function is present, but I'm not able to use with mydiagram model

Answer (score 0):

This is merely a problem in your TypeScript code.  Cast the model to be of type **TreeModel**.

```
(myDiagram.model as go.TreeModel).setParentKeyForNodeData(...)
```

You can definitely use the latest versions of GoJS and gojs-angular.